# Connect two 12-polygons in 3d space

Tags: python, c++, 3d, polygon, computational-geometry

Given I have two polygons with 12 vertices (Only vertices are shown, not edges) which lie in two different planes.

I need to take pairs of vertices (i, j) of polygon on the left (polygon A) and connect these vertices to vertices (k,l) of the polygon on the right (polygon B) by edges. (The four points i, j, k, l will form a quadrilateral). I have the additional constraint, that the quadrilaterals will not intersect with each other.

[image: Two polygons in 3d]

What I tried so far:
I) Project all vertices of polygon B to the plane of polygon A. Then take closest vertex pairs. This does not work in the general case.
II) Project all vertices of polygon B to the plane of polygon A. Then determine minimal angles between vertices of polygon A and B. This does not work in the general case.

Anybody can think of a strategy how to accomplish this?

(No, this is no homework! :) I'm embarrassed by myself that I have to reveal this question here and that I seem to be unable to solve this seemingly trivial problem alone)

Comment: When you say 'take pairs' do you mean: for every pair of vertices from A find a pair from B, or for a given set of pairs from A or what?

Comment: By take pairs I mean: Label the vertices in polygon A by numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 in let's say CCW or CW order, do the same for the vertices in polygon B by numbers: 1', 2', 3', 4', 5', 6', 7', 8', 9', 10', 11', 12'. Then for each pair of the polygon A  take vertex pairs (1,2) and find a pair in polygon B, take pair (2,3) in polygon A and find a pair in polygon B, repeat up to vertex pair (11,12) of polygon A.

Comment: Are the polygons related in any way? For example are they the same 2d polygon projected onto different 3d planes? Further, you say that the pair from one polygon and the pair from the other form a quadrilateral; but while this figure will have 4 vertices it seems unlikely to me that it will always be planar, that is that all 4 points will be in a plane. What 3d locus will you use for intersection tests?

Comment: @dmuir: They are not related. I want to create a quadrilateral from the 4 vertices (2 from polygon A and two from polygon B). They are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

Calculate centroid of polygon A and B, call this C_A and C_B.
Then shift points of polygon A or B towards polygon A or B in direction of d = C_A - C_B or d = C_B - C_A, call these shifted points A' or B'.

Next, find nearest neighbor vertices (u, v) of shifted polygon (A' or B') and one of the original polygons (A or B). Start from this pair (u, v) and sort vertices CCW or CW iteratively.